# Как освободить память после (VARIANT*)malloc(sizeof(VARIANT))

Tags: c++, qt, memory, утечка-памяти, malloc

Таким образом выделяется память под переменную:

```
VARIANT *theItem = (VARIANT*)malloc(sizeof(VARIANT));
```

Не free, не delete не удаляют выделенную память, хотя, я могу ошибаться.
Вот полный код:

```
VARIANT *theItem = (VARIANT*)malloc(sizeof(VARIANT));
if (enumInterface->Next(1,theItem,NULL) == S_FALSE)
  return false;

item = new QAxObject((IUnknown*)theItem->punkVal);
qDebug() << theItem;
free(theItem);
qDebug() << theItem;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить утечку памяти?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что free не освобождает память? Начнем с этого :-)

Comment: Память не освободится, только если управление перейдёт у строке `return false`.

Comment: Про return false уже заметил, а malloc я взял из примера одного, и, когда попробовал переписать через new, случилась какая - то ошибка и я вернул на malloc. Сейчас уже исправил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Память-то освобождается. А вот адрес в указателе theItem остается старый. Только  теперь он указывает на мусор, а не на выделенную память. И если вы попробуете этот невалидный указатель использовать, например для записи, вашей программе может быть больно))

И, кстати, если

```
if (enumInterface->Next(1,theItem,NULL) == S_FALSE)
  return false;
```

сработает, то ваш код освобождения памяти не будет выполнен. Что потенциально влечет утечку памяти. В связи с этим рекомендую ознакомиться с концепцией RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) вообще, и smart pointers в частности - как раз придумано для изящного решения подобных проблем.

И еще непонятно, почему вы юзаете malloc вместо new.

Comment: Я поторопился с выводами, не из - за этого память утекает, просто подумал на это место. Благодарю за ответ.